# Зачем нужны в php статические методы и свойства?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

Как используется в php статические методы и свойства?  Одно из применений это реализация паттерна singleton. Есть ли еще практические примеры их использования?
Буду рад примеру где с помощью фабричного метода, была решена задача, которая без него решалась сложнее.

Comment: Классическим использованием статических переменных является задача счетчика созданных объектов.

Comment: какое ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ  значение имеет сколько у меня экземпляров класса создано, если решено что можно создавать больше одного?

Comment: Например, это соединения с базой данных или с каким-то другим ресурсом, которых вам разрешено создать не более пяти штук. Счетчик объектов тут пригодится.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использовать статические функции класса можно, не создавая самого экземпляра класса. Т.е. вам не нужно создавать объект. (ну я думаю суть понята)
Плюсы тут в том что объект может иметь некоторые методы которые могут быть использованы как в контексте данного объекта так и без него...

Пример:  есть объект 'Сотрудник' и есть метод 'Узнать всех кто работает в компании', да создав такой объект вы можете захотеть узнать кто же работает в компании, (т.е. сам сотрудник это узнает), но вы также можете захотеть это узнать (не афишируя кто именно воспользовался узнаванием), т.е. не создавая вообще объекта сотрудник. В данном случае у вас по сути данный статический метод практически является обычной функцией , которая не зависит от класса.

Статические переменные наделены другим свойством, создавая различные экземпляры объектов, их свойства будут ссылаться на один участок памяти. Т.е. меняя статические свойства в одном объекте они будут изменяться и в других объектах (созданных на базе данного класса) автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Наибольший эффект это даёт, когда действительно нужно реализовать работу фабрики. К примеру: нужно получить новый ассоциативный массив данных, на основе одного или двух массивов.

Каждый элемент окончательного массива получаем с помощью различных сложных преобразований в различных функциях. Так вот, чтобы не плодить различные передачи и присвоения данных в функциях расчета, очень удобно использовать `static`: это экономит память, время на различных присвоениях и тому подобное.

```
class A {
    static a;
    static b;
    static c = [];
}

class SetA extends A{
    // Километровый код расчёта этих переменных
}

class GetA extends A{
    // Функции, дающие возможность получить доступ
    // к этим трем переменным.
}
```

Если не использовать `static`, то функции придется писать вот так:

```
function a(array $param = null){

    $paramA = $param['a'];
    $paramB = $param['b'];

    /* чёт делаем */

    $param['newA'] = $paramA;    
    $param['newB'] = $paramB;

    return $param;    
}
```

И таким образом будет выглядеть каждая функция без `static`. Очень полезна для построения календаря, различных матриц и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

использование статических методов в php абсолютно ничем не отличается от использования статических методов в других языках программирования.

Например их можно использовать ВМЕСТО паттерна синглтон.

Comment: конкретный практический пример можете привести? Какая ПРАКТИЧЕСКАЯ   выгода от использования ?

Comment: Например экономия памяти

Answer (score 0):

На ваш вопрос сложно ответить. Статический контекст - это инструмент, а когда его применять и обосновано ли его применение в данной задаче - это уже более субъективные рамки, которые зависят скорее от вас.

Статический контекст можно рассматривать с (как минимум) двух точек зрения: как область для обслуживания некоторого функционала, связанного со спецификой класса (те самые синглтон, фабричные методы и счетчики экземпляров, хранение метаданных), так и как область для обслуживания функционала, не привязанного к конкретному экземпляру (например, любой метод, не требующий состояния, можно реализовать в статическом исполнении, `Math::factorial(12)` проще, чем `(new Math())->factorial(12)` и требует меньше затрат на реализацию).

И то, и другое можно реализовать без статики (однако, как можно судить по примеру выше, это не всегда практично), поэтому нельзя сказать, что статика существует ради этих вещей. Если вы пытаетесь найти область применения, в которой она незаменима, то я не уверен, что это возможно; опять же, это просто инструмент для реализации.

Comment: Так то все Вы правильно говорите), но этот пост я написал с целью, чтобы кто то поделился практическим примером применения который принес счастье при разработке программы ))) за счет чего можно понять  семантику  статических методов.

Comment: @heff *но этот пост я написал с целью, чтобы кто то поделился практическим примером применения который принес счастье при разработке программы* - говорю же - *это инструмент, а когда его применять и обосновано ли его применение в данной задаче - это уже более субъективные рамки, которые зависят скорее от вас*